# How to make a $http request from the rest client in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

Have this scenario when I make a request via $http in the first service, and then I want to manipulate the data in other service. For some reassons my returned object is empty. Any advice ?

```
.factory('widgetRestService',['$http','$log',function($http,$log){

  var serviceInstance = {};
  serviceInstance.getInfo = function(){
    var request = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/rest/widgets/getListInfoDashboards'})
      .then(function(success){
        serviceInstance.widgets = success.data;
        $log.debug('serviceInstance.widgets SUCCESS',serviceInstance.widgets);
      },function(error){
        $log.debug('Error ', error);
        $log.debug('serviceInstance.widgets ERROR',serviceInstance.widgets);
      });
    return request;
  };

  serviceInstance.getAllWidgets = function () {
    if (serviceInstance.widgets) {
      return serviceInstance.widgets;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  };

  return serviceInstance;

}])

.factory('OtherService',['widgetRestService','$log', function(widgetRestService, $log){

   widgetRestService.getInfo();

   // and now I want to return widgetRestService.widgets [{things},{things},{things}]
  return widgetRestService.getAllWidgets(); // returns []

 }])
```

> Result: [ ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wait for your HTTP request to complete before trying to access the data that it returns. You can do this by accessing `getAllWidgets` within a `then` attached to the Promise returned by `getInfo`.

```
.factory('OtherService', ['widgetRestService','$log', function(widgetRestService, $log) {
   return widgetRestService.getInfo().then(function () {
       return widgetRestService.getAllWidgets();
   });
 }])
```

Consume `OtherService` somewhere:

```
OtherService.then(function (widgets) {
    // do something with `widgets`...
});
```

Comment: The OtherService needs to return and array, If put the return statement inside the then function callback, my factory doesn`t return anything....

Comment: You cannot return a value produced asynchronously in the way that you want. You can return a Promise in `OtherService` that gives you the data. Please see my amended answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have to return promise instead of response to get the data from another service.

```
serviceInstance.getInfo = function(){
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/rest/widgets/getListInfoDashboards'})
    .then(function(success){
        deferred.resolve(success.data);
    },function(error){
        $log.debug('Error ', error);
        $log.debug('serviceInstance.widgets ERROR',serviceInstance.widgets);
    });
return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: How to I access the value key inside deferred ? (tried deferred.promise.$$state.value; but doesn`t work)

Answer (score 1):

`widgetRestService.getInfo()` is returning a promise, so you have to wait for its resolution:

```js
.factory("OtherService", ["widgetRestService", "$log", "$q"
function (widgetRestService, $log, $q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  widgetRestService.getInfo().then(function () {
     // only here, you're sure `serviceInstance.widgets` has been set (unless an error occurred when requesting the api)
    deferred.resolve(widgetRestService.getAllWidgets());
  });

  return deferred.promise;

}])
```

Then, e.g. in a controller:

```js
.controller("SomeController", ["$scope", "OtherService"
function ($scope, OtherService) {

  OtherService.then(function (allWidgets) {
    $scope.allWidgets = allWidgets;
  });

}])
```

Comment: How to I access the value key inside deferred ? (tried deferred.promise.$$state.value; but doesn`t work)